# How to cut Patio Pavers

Tags: tools, landscaping, patio, pavers, saw

I would like to lay patio pavers for a patio in a diagonal fashion.  I would like to know what kind of tool I should use to cut the pavers in half.  They are about 2" thick, and I'd like to not use the Hammer and Chisel approach so I can get clean edges.  Is there a particular kind of blade I can put in a circular saw to do this job?  Since this patio is going to be over 200 square feet, I would be willing to purchase a new tool if needed to save me time on this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably rent a saw like this from your local hardware store.

[image: Wet Brick Saw]

They will usually have a diamond tipped masonry blade. You'll also want to make sure it's a wet saw or you keep the stones wet as you cut, as the dust from cutting concrete can make a real mess and be harmful to your health.

You may also be able to find a splitter like this.

[image: Paver Splitter]

The splitters produce far less dust and noise, and can usually be found cheaper than a saw (I found a couple on-line for a few hundred dollars).  However, splitters may not produce a perfectly clean cut. Splitters also come in pneumatic and hydraulic varieties, purchasing those might be out of the budget ($1000.00 and up) but might be available for rent at a reasonable price.

Comment: I've used both and would also recommend the splitter just to avoid the dust. That said, you will not get a super clean break like you will with a diamond saw.

Comment: Keep in mind that the splitter option is much faster than the saw option.

Comment: Certain Paver styles lend them selves to one type of cut verses the other. You should use a saw for pavers that have a clean look. The splitter should be used for pavers that have a rustic look.

Comment: I've found a splitter (a more basic model than the one pictured) to work well for right angle cuts around the middle of the paver across the short dimension, but for other types of cuts it would often break the wrong way and would take several attempts (new paver each time) or not work at all and I'd have to use a small angle grinder with a diamond blade.